# How to add new value to listpreference and save it?

Tags: android, listpreference

I have a list Preference that created from resource xml. I added preference that created dialog in which user can add value to listPreference.

using those methods i added new value:

```
  entries = getEntries();
  entryValues = getEntryValues();
```

when user is adding values to listpreference, its displayed. But when preferenceScreen is recreating new value disappearing.

How can i save those new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that when you're reopening your `PreferenceScreen`, it loads the `ListPreference`'s values from XML. You can change this behavior using the `setEntries()` and `setEntryVaues()` methods of `ListPreference`. Of course you need to somehow store all the values and their indexes that your users enter. You can use databases or `SharedPreferences` for it. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Saving the value of a `ListPreference` into the `SharedPreferences`:

```
preferences.edit().putString(listPreference.getKey(), listPreference.getValue());
```

Comment: could you please give example how to use editor to save listprefrence?

Comment: sorry but this will save only choose option. how can i save whole new list with values - entryValues?

Comment: @user1150489, You can use different methods to store a bunch of Strings, or store them inside a database.

Comment: Yes, as alternative. I think there is a ready way to do this :)