# Dynamically adding options to a listpreference

Tags: java, android, listpreference

I am writing a program that has a `PreferenceActivity` and multiple `PreferenceFragment`. One of the options the user selects is a server to connect to, this is populated from the XML.

```
<string-array name="server_names">
    <item>test</item>
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="server_addresses">
    <item>10.10.10.1</item> 
    <item>10.10.10.2</item>
    <item>10.10.10.3</item>
</string-array>
```

This obviously works fine and you get the three names in the list. However there is a separate fragment that allows the user to enter a name and ip address which is then added to the drop down as an extra option.

I have got a working solution that involved loading an external file, clearing the entries and adding the ones from the file. This is 'ok' but I want to use `sharedpreferences` to save these extra values. My question is this, how do I use the editor to write extra options that will be saved each time the app is launched?

I have looked at using the `Editor`, `putStringSet` and `commit` but the added option doesn't appear in the drop down. There are related posts that seem to deal with a `TextPreference` but those solutions haven't solved my problem.

**edit, this is how i create my ListPreference:**

```
    <ListPreference
      android:entries="@array/server_names"
      android:entryValues="@array/server_addresses"
      android:key="@string/countryListId"
      android:negativeButtonText="@null"
      android:positiveButtonText="@null"
      android:title="@string/pref_title_select_com_target"
      android:enabled="true"
    android:shouldDisableView="false" />
```

I have a click handler on a label to add to the ListPreference:

```
 public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Add new server")
                        .setMessage("Confirm you wish to add the server?")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

       /*  command in here to edit the server_names and server_addresses */   
                            }})
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();


                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I think you've given me a good lead, I am trying something out now. I believe I misunderstood SharedPreferences vs DefaultSharedPreferences. I am looking into using setEntries and will accept answer if that works.. thanks for your help!

Comment: have you succeeded? :D

Comment: Essentially yes, I used putStringSet to save the values and get stringset for loading. I had a couple of other issues related to ordering the two arrays but they were overcome. Thanks for your help your answer put me on the right track.

Comment: Glad to help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write to shared pref

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("highscore", 5);
editor.commit();
```

Read from:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = 0;
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt("highscore"), defaultValue);
```

Is this what you are asking?

EDIT:

Looking at your code, you seem to be missing the actual saving.

Check the answer from Gregor:
[How to add new value to listpreference and save it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429796/how-to-add-new-value-to-listpreference-and-save-it)

He basically says that everytime you open your dialog, the list from xml is loaded. You need to change the behaviour to include the preferences from the SharedPreferences.

> You can change this behavior using the setEntries() and
>   setEntryVaues() methods of ListPreference

Comment: I was looking at that from the documentation I just can't get it to adapt for a ListPreference. I have used putStringSet but the change isn't reflected in the drop down.

Comment: when you read from the shared preference, you have to add it to adapter of the dropdown yourself.

Comment: After adding it, you might also have to call notifyDatasetChanged()? Dont know what kind of implementation you are using for your dropdown.

Comment: I have added to my question to better highlight what isn't working, I wasn't sure if when you commit it automatically generates an on update to the UI.